# How can I delete multiple folders with by name using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, directory, purge

I have a list of folders that have to get deleted in a directory and I'm trying to purge them all at once. Looking to be able to delete the folders in a directory based on the list of names

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `Get-ChildItem` and `Remove-Item` cmdlet.

Comment: Thanks Martin! I'm still extremely new to Powershell. If I research the above I should be able to write something up?